# Serialize 2 properties with the same name but different attributes

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

I'm getting an error when I try to serialize my class. The xml schema is defined by a third-party and I can't change it.

The xml looks like this (snippet only btw):

```
<order>
<date type="received-date">20160810</date>
<date type="required-date">20160810</date>
<reference type="cust-order-no">CCCC</reference>
<reference type="an-2">AAAA</reference>
<reference type="an-3">BBBB</reference>
<order>
```

I've defined the following class for my order date

```
[Serializable]
public class OrderDate
{
    public enum OrderDateTypeEnum
    {
        [Description("entered-date")]
        EnteredDate,
        [Description("received-date")]
        ReceivedDate,
        [Description("required-date")]
        RequiredDate
    }

    private OrderDateTypeEnum _typeEnum;

    [XmlIgnore]
    public OrderDateTypeEnum TypeEnum
    {
        get { return this._typeEnum; }
        set
        {
            this._typeEnum = value;
            this.Type = this._typeEnum.GetDescription();
        }
    }

    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and the order class is defined as:

```
[Serializable]
public class Order
{
    [XmlElement("date")]
    public OrderDate EnteredDate { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("date")]
    public OrderDate ReceivedDate { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("date")]
    public OrderDate RequiredDate { get; set; }
}
```

but when I serialize this, I get an error:

```
The XML element 'date' from namespace '' is already present in the current
scope. Use XML attributes to specify another XML name or namespace for the
element.
```

When I remove the `[XmlElement("date")]`, it works but my xml is not formatted the way I needed it to.

I'll have the exact same problem with reference when I get to it.

How can I circumvent this problem?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `[XmlElement("received-date")]` instead of `[XmlElement("date")]` for the `ReceivedDate` Property ? Same goes for required date. And I see no `EnteredDate` in your XML.

Comment: @user3185569, ideally yes, but if you do what you suggested, the note won't be <date type="received-date"/> but instead it will be <received-date type="received-date" /> which is no good in my scenario as remember I can't change the format in which the xml is presented to me as it's coming from a third-party.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this and map to `Order` as you've defined it without implementing `IXmlSerializable` yourself.  What you can do is use a single `List<OrderDate>` property:

```
[XmlRoot("order")]
public class Order
{
    [XmlElement("date")]
    public List<OrderDate> Dates { get; set; }
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fMaTVi) for a working demo. You could add various (ignored) properties to query the dates for each type if you wished.

As an aside, the `[Serializable]` attribute has nothing to do with `XmlSerializer` and can be removed.

Comment: Thanks for that Charles. It works using a list but I really wish I could change that schema as I really don't like the way it's formatted.